# Linear regression – discrepancy between R and Excel - what mistake did I do?

Tags: r, excel, linear-regression

I made a series of linear regression of variables X vs. Y. The model is Y=f(X), with intercept forced to 0. I computed it under R and obtained results.

Later, I did some of the same linear regressions on Excel again (as a control, first time in R). I obtained slightly different results (slope is sometimes different, R-squared are lower). I don’t exactly know where it comes from, my first assumption is that I coded wrongly on R.

Here is the R code (with some data):

```
X=c(513,474,313,449,401,266,542,522,391,498,446,279)
Y=c(446,439,344,393,345,209,478,482,315,440,401,278)

reg_lin=lm(Y ~ X + 0)
slope=round(summary(reg_lin)$coefficients[1], digits=4)
reg_R2=round(summary(reg_lin)$r.squared, digits=3)

print(slope)
# 0.8946
print(reg_R2)
# 0.996

# to be used (I let it in case it’s relevant, as it shows later use of confidence intervals)
# seq_IC95=seq(from=0, to=542, by=1) # 542 is the max of Y
# IC95=predict(reg_lin, newdata = data.frame(X = seq_IC95), interval = "confidence", level = 0.95)
```

With the same X and Y, I obtained the following results in Excel (linear regression on a plot, intercept forced to 0 as well):
-   slope= 0.8946
-   R-squared=0.899

In this case the slope is the same in R and Excel, but R-squared is a bit different. Any advice on where to check/what to correct?

Comment: I think it just shows that R is better than Excel because its R2 is higher.  Kidding aside, computing an R-square by hand is a good exercise so maybe you can compare the two methods to find out more...

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-does-summary_0028_0029-report-strange-results-for-the-R_005e2-estimate-when-I-fit-a-linear-model-with-no-intercept_003f

Comment: Hope You don't mine, but why u force intercept to be 0? In this case the coefficients go crazy.

Comment: by the way, if you have a reproducible example where the slope differs, you can post that as a separate question -- it's not covered by the duplicated answer.  In the example you show the slope is identical, which is what's expected.

Comment: @ Dirk: if no one on the forum sees a mistake in the code, then a question of software/algorithm it is. I'll do the calculation by hand later in the afternoon - good exercise indeed.

Comment: @ Adii: because I think it makes more sense biologically speaking. Not sure though - have to discuss it with colleagues. If I don't force the intercept "R" R-squared becomes close to Excel's, but still differs (0.903).

Comment: @Thomas are you sure the difference isn't just one of reporting precision? R reports 0.9031495 for R^2 -- what does Excel say?

Comment: @ Ben: sorry was looking at your comment. If I don't force intercept in R and Excel, slopes are the same. Which means my post is a duplicate of the one you directed me to. I searched with the wrong keywords. Very sorry for that, how can I delete the thread? And thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Thomas It may be biological more plausible for the intercept to be 0, but unless you have data without error, or even if the sample of data you have is a little odd, it may well be better to allow a non-zero intercept to be fit.